# My 4k screen is smaller then the computer thinks

Tags: multiple-monitors, desktop-computer

I have 2 screens. One is [a 1280x1024, 17" Dell](https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-ultrasharp/specs/) and the other one is [a 3840x2160 23.6" Samsung](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/uhd-and-wqhd/samsung-uhd-23-6-monitor-with-high-glossy-black-finish-lu24e590ds-za/). Alas, my Samsung registers as roughly twice the size it's supposed to, and although there is but a 1 inch height difference between the two, I must move my cursor halfway up the screen to reach the Dell.

It currently acts like this:

[image]

When it should be acting like this:

[image]

I have a GTX 1060 if that helps at all.

Comment: I've only had one "beyond 1080p" monitor so far, and it only regisitered as "larger than it was" when it was restricted to 1080p resolution by hardware/cable driving it. Once an appropriate cable was sourced it got the right size as well as full resolution. So you might want to check if you are getting the full resolution on that display, first.

Comment: If your Samsung monitor is 3840x2160, as you say, then the first diagram looks correct, while the second would be correct for 1920x1080. Is the Samsung set into some sort of compatibility mode via its panel settings? You should be able to use advanced settings to choose the lower resolution.

Comment: @AFH the real life size ratio between the two monitors is that of the second picture, while the computer uses the pixel ratio in the first picture. I would like to be able to keep my current resolution, while being able to move my mouse between the two properly.

Comment: Your real-life size ratio is 3840x2160 as against 1280x1024, as per the first picture. You'll need to clarify what you are doing or attempting to do.

Comment: Your first picture is 'correct'. To achieve your 2nd picture you'll need to reduce your lovely hi-res monitor's resolution down to something nearer the smaller one. The computer doesn't care what the dimensions of the screen are, only the number of pixels it's displaying, so your new screen isn't "a bit bigger" than your old one, it's 8 times the size.